# Characters overflowing container

Tags: html, css

[image: This is the problem]

So basically this is my problem i have a div that gets its value from a `<textarea>` just like here on Stack Overflow but if I make it into big characters or small the characters won't break to a new line -- they go outside of the `<div>`. is there a easy and good way to resolve this?

Comment: What would you like to see when the text *overflows* its container?

Comment: i would like it to brake to another line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following CSS on your element:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you i knew that there was a simple solution to this i would have gone and made 100 loops Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `word-wrap`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7vDbp/

Usage notes: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Alternately, you can insert the `<wbr/>` tag into your markup at desired word breaks.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wz8jp/